# creating a new object with nested resources #rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a rails application that creates a notebook and within the notebook, notes. I am writing a form  to create a new note but I am confused how to the format the form. This is what I currently have:

notebook/id/note/new -> view

```
= form_for [@notebook, @note] do |note|
  == note.label :title
  == note.text_field :title
  br
  == note.text_field :body
  br
  == note.submit :save
```

NotesController ->

```
  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end


 def create
    @note = @notebook.notes.create(notes_params)
    @note.user = current_user
    redirect_to @notebook
 end

  my routes: 
     resources :notebooks  do
       resources :notes 
     end
```

The error I am receiving says

```
 undefined method `notes_path' for #objectnumber
```

Comment: can you plz share your route file?

Comment: I just update my question with my routes

Comment: How are you loading/assigning @notebook in your controller?

Comment: `== link_to new_notebook_note_path(@notebook)`

this is how I call the new action from the @notebook's show action

Comment: But how are where are you assigning @notebook ?

Comment: `== link_to new_notebook_note_path(@notebook)` this is how I am calling the new action. But when I check the @notebook value when I reach the new action page, it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

Since `notes` is a nested resource under `notebooks`, the `form_for` method needs a little help with the url. It's trying to create a path from the `note` passed into the block, but you need to specify that the url is nested, like so:

```
= form_for [@notebook, @note], url: notebook_note_path(@notebook, @note) do |note|
```

See the [Rails Guides page on creating urls and paths](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) for more detailed info.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but ended up with no route matches error.